# PHP GD library is NOT installed but it has been enabled actually

Tags: php, gd, php-7, php-7.2

I have PHP GD installed and enabled:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

But I cannot find it on the `phpinfo();` screen, nor can I find it using the code below:

```
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
    echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
}
else {
    echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";
}
```

Result: **PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server**

I am on PHP 7.0:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 (cli) (built: Aug  8 2017 22:03:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Any idea why and how I can fix it?

I am on Kubuntu 17.10 btw

If I go ahead installing it again:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php7.0-gd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php7.0-gd' has no installation candidate
```

Why??

**EDIT 1:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-gd is already the newest version (1:7.1+54ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 86 not to upgrade.
```

**EDIT 2:**

But there is something strange - I am on PHP 7.0 but the GD below is php7.1-gd,

```
$ sudo apt-cache search php7-* 
libapache2-mod-php7.1 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
php-all-dev - package depending on all supported PHP development packages
php7.1 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.1-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.1-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.1-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.1-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.1-dev - Files for PHP7.1 module development
php7.1-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.1-gmp - GMP module for PHP
php7.1-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.1-ldap - LDAP module for PHP
php7.1-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.1-odbc - ODBC module for PHP
php7.1-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.1-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP
php7.1-pspell - pspell module for PHP
php7.1-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.1-recode - recode module for PHP
php7.1-snmp - SNMP module for PHP
php7.1-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP
php7.1-tidy - tidy module for PHP
php7.1-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.1-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
libphp7.1-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
php-amqp - AMQP extension for PHP
php-apcu - APC User Cache for PHP
php-ds - PHP extension providing efficient data structures for PHP 7
php-gearman - PHP wrapper to libgearman
php-geoip - GeoIP module for PHP
php-gmagick - Provides a wrapper to the GraphicsMagick library
php-gnupg - PHP wrapper around the gpgme library
php-http - PECL HTTP module for PHP Extended HTTP Support
php-igbinary - igbinary PHP serializer
php-imagick - Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
php-libsodium - PHP wrapper for the Sodium cryptographic library
php-mailparse - Email message manipulation for PHP
php-memcache - memcache extension module for PHP
php-memcached - memcached extension module for PHP, uses libmemcached
php-mongodb - MongoDB driver for PHP
php-msgpack - PHP extension for interfacing with MessagePack
php-oauth - OAuth 1.0 consumer and provider extension
php-pinba - Pinba module for PHP
php-propro - propro module for PHP
php-ps - ps module for PHP
php-radius - radius client library for PHP
php-raphf - raphf module for PHP
php-redis - PHP extension for interfacing with Redis
php-remctl - PECL module for Kerberos-authenticated command execution
php-rrd - PHP bindings to rrd tool system
php-sass - PHP bindings to libsass - fast, native Sass parsing in PHP
php-smbclient - PHP wrapper for libsmbclient
php-solr - PHP extension for communicating with Apache Solr server
php-ssh2 - Bindings for the libssh2 library
php-stomp - Streaming Text Oriented Messaging Protocol (STOMP) client module for PHP
php-symfony-polyfill-php70 - Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
php-tideways - Tideways PHP Profiler Extension
php-uploadprogress - file upload progress tracking extension for PHP
php-uuid - PHP UUID extension
php-xdebug - Xdebug Module for PHP
php-yac - YAC (Yet Another Cache) for PHP
php-yaml - YAML-1.1 parser and emitter for PHP
php-zmq - ZeroMQ messaging bindings for PHP
php7.1-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP
php7.1-bz2 - bzip2 module for PHP
php7.1-dba - DBA module for PHP
php7.1-enchant - Enchant module for PHP
php7.1-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
php7.1-imap - IMAP module for PHP
php7.1-interbase - Interbase module for PHP
php7.1-intl - Internationalisation module for PHP
php7.1-mapi - Complete and feature rich groupware solution - PHP MAPI bindings
php7.1-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
php7.1-mcrypt - libmcrypt module for PHP
php7.1-phpdbg - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)
php7.1-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.1-sybase - Sybase module for PHP
php7.1-xsl - XSL module for PHP (dummy)
php7.1-zip - Zip module for PHP
php7cc - command line tool to detect PHP 7 incompatible code
php7.0-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.0-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.0-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.0-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.0-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
libapache2-mod-php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
php7.0-mcrypt - libmcrypt module for PHP
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
php7.0-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
php7.0-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.0-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.0-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
```

Is this causing the problem? Should I uninstall php7.1-gd?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: @BenFortune yes many times

Comment: Does installing php-gd work? (BTW .dll files are for Windows)

Comment: @NigelRen see my edit above. thanks

Comment: Have you tried running a web page with just `phpinfo();` - this tells you if the extension is there and which .ini file it's using to check.

Comment: @NigelRen done that just as I have mentioned it already in my question above.

Comment: You've run the CLI version of PHP to check what is installed, this may be configured differently to your web server version of PHP (the version run through Apache in your case).

Comment: @NigelRen what can I do now then?

Comment: Create a page as with `phpinfo();` in it in your document root and then in a browser open this page.

Comment: @NigelRen done that just as I mentioned it already.

Comment: I have the impression that you've installed PHP/7.0 manually and completely bypassing Ubuntu package system (you even have configuration files for Microsoft Windows!). If that's the case, you should really clean up all the mess and stick to apt-get. But the problem of not using packages in the first place is that stuff can be scattered everywhere and there's no way to say where.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález what do you mean `manually`? don't we all install it like so `$ sudo apt install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0`?

Comment: I can't know what you or your predecessors did. As I said, it's just an impression (judging from the Windows settings).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't understand when it is said above is a Windows setting. I did exactly the same from this guide for Ubuntu https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: That tutorial does not have the "dll" substring anywhere. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) / [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815065/what-is-a-dll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working following these 3 steps:

1. **uninstalled** PHP and all its libs from my machine following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-completely-remove-php).
2. **upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04** following this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BionicUpgrades/Kubuntu).
3. **installed PHP 7.2** following this [guide](https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/).*

On my terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php

$ sudo apt-get install php-pear php-fpm php-dev php-zip php-curl php-xmlrpc php-gd php-mysql php-mbstring php-xml libapache2-mod-php

$ php -v
PHP 7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: May  9 2018 17:21:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Result:

[image]

It took a few hours but worth it!